# SQL Server 2019 CPU spikes with no usage

Tags: sql-server-2019, cpu

We've configured two SQL Server 2019 VM one it's primary and other secondary, both take part in an Availability Group.

The primary node have CPU spikes every 30 min and there isn't any job, heavy query, process in background executed(at least visible).

Process "SQL Server Windows NT - 64 bit" consumes ~90% CPU but we are not capable to detect the CPU consuming cause.

[image]

Comment: What does [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) show if you run it during the CPU spike?

Comment: How many CPU cores does the primary have?

Comment: @JoshDarnell 4 vcpus. Azure VM D4s v3 (4 vcpus, 16 GiB memory).

If the databases are offline then CPU spikes stop.

Comment: @J.D. nothing relevant executing sp_WhoIsActive.

Comment: Hi there, problem was detected. DB's had the change tracking option enabled so after disable it CPU consumption went down.